# Addition subtraction not yielding the expected result

Tags: assembly, masm

The following code displays `+49086` 
The calculation that I am doing is : `Z1 = (var1 + 10) - (100 + var2)`
var1 = 24 , var2 = 4000h = 16384 
So Z1 = 24 + 10 - 100 - 16384 = `-16450`, What could be the reason that instead of this 
+49086 is getting displayed

```
    .386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
var1    byte    24
var2    word    4000h
var3    dword   0FFFF0000h
Z1    dword    ?
Z2    dword    ?
Z3    dword    ?
Z4    dword    ?

.code
main proc
xor eax, eax
mov al, var1
add al, 10

xor ebx, ebx
mov bx, var2
add bx, 100

sub ax,bx
mov Z1, eax
call writeint

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Did you read my comment on your previous question about this code ([Writeint not displaying the value in EAX register](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120074440))?   I assume that was you, since the only change is a bugfix of operand-order in `mov Z1, eax`.  My comment I already pointed out the problem of doing a narrow subtract, and suggested a fix.  (do a 32-bit subtract since you already have values zero-extended to 32-bit.)

Comment: Anyway, you have a 16-bit negative number *zero*-extended to 32-bit, and you're printing the 32-bit number.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks that worked. I have one more similar doubt but I will post that as a separate question instead.